# Disable Navigation Drawer on start

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want my navigation drawer to be disabled as the application loaded, and if user to some certain tasks it would be enabled.

in brief is there a way to disable navigation drawer's toggle button, and enable it again with subject to a user action.

Edit :
I have updated my activity as follows;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        DrawerLayout navigationDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                navigationDrawerLayout);

        navigationDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    ...
}
```

but when the application launches I can open navigation drawer, which I don t desire

Answer (score 4):

You just have to lock and unlock your `DrawerLayout` using `DrawerLayout` `setDrawerLockMode()` method.

So, for locking your `DrawerLayout` in close mode, use:

```
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

If you prefer to lock it in open mode, use `drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);`

Finally, when you want to unlock your `DrawerLayout`, use:

```
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Comment: I have just tried your solution but it did not worked, please have a look at my update on question

Comment: What is happening, then?

Comment: the drawer is still openable

Comment: does it open when you click the action bar home button or by swipe or both?

Comment: it opens only as i click the action bar home button.

Comment: Could you please show your code inside onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62013/discussion-between-dursun-and-joao2fast4u).

Answer (score 0):

```
write condtion in onoptionsitemselected and block it


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
if(yourconditionsatisfied)
{
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinearLayout)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinearLayout);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLinearLayout);
            }
    }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: So, you want to lock your drawer in close mode and then unlock it with some user action?

Comment: my question is about the navigationDrawer not the optionsmenu

Comment: you want to disable or you want to hide the navigationdrawer icon

Comment: NavigationDrawer open on clicking android home button thats why iwrote that code please run the code i have written it will work